# Batch script deleting itself

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have a `.bat` script launching a `java` program. 
The `java` program deletes the folder where the `.bat` sits.
I have no way to touch the `java` program. I only can modify the `.bat` file.

The problem is that the `.bat` file, once deleted, stops its execution right away without finishing. 
But there are some cleanup tasks to be done after the `java` program exits.

I tried to copy the `.bat` file somewhere else and launch it in a location where it would not be deleted. Alas, once the original `.bat` is deleted, because it is still in execution, the same crash happens and it does not finish.

Here are two sample files (for the purpose of the example, let's pretend they are located in `D:\tmp`) :

**delete.bat**

```
echo "delete start"

pause

del launch.bat

pause

echo "delete end"
```

**launch.bat**

```
echo "launch start"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions 

if "%CD%"=="C:\tmp" (

    echo "in temp"
    d:
    cd \tmp
    delete.bat

)

if "%CD%" NEQ "C:\tmp" (

    echo "not in temp"
    mkdir C:\tmp
    copy launch.bat C:\tmp\launch.bat
    echo "launch copied"
    C:
    cd \tmp
    cmd /c launch.bat

)

echo "launch end"
```

Launching `launch.bat` would work if the execution of the copied `launch.bat` were separated from the initial one.

Does anyone know a way to make a `.bat` end up its execution even if it is deleted while it executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have a better result by doing it like this (calling `launch.bat` with `cmd /k`) :

**launch.bat**

```
echo "launch start"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions 

if "%CD%"=="C:\tmp" (

        echo "in temp"
        d:
        cd \tmp
        delete.bat
        echo "after delete"
)

if "%CD%" NEQ "C:\tmp" (

        echo "not in temp"
        mkdir C:\tmp
        copy launch.bat C:\tmp\launch.bat
        echo "launch copied"
        C:
        cd \tmp
        cmd /k launch.bat

)

echo "launch end"
```

Now I can reach the `echo "after delete"`, but I end up somehow in an infinite loop. At least my clean up can be executed at this point. Don't know why I can't reach  `echo "launch end"`, though.

Answer (score 3):

This will command the script to delete itself then exit. The entire line is read by the command interpreter before the line is executed so the exit command will be executed after the delete command even though the file no longer exists.

```
del /f/q "%~0" | exit
```

Alternatively, you can use parentheses if you want to execute many commands after the file has been deleted as the command interpreter will read everything inside the parentheses before executing it.

```
(del /f/q "%~0"
if exist "%~0" (echo.How did that happen?) else (echo.I've deleted myself.)
pause
exit)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to execute lines from a deleted file, but the lines have to reside in a parenthesis block, as blocks are always cached completly into memory before they are executed.

Obviously you can't call functions in the batch, but it's possible to call other batch files and get the control back (into the block).

```
@echo off
(
  echo Delete myself
  del %~f0
  call ..\second.bat 
  echo do some other stuff after second.bat
)
echo This line can't be reached anymore
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know a way to make a .bat end up its execution even if it is deleted while it executes ?

I don't think it is possible. Batch execution read directly from the file. If you modify the file, it will change the execution (self-modifying batch programs are wonderfully difficult to debug!)

Why don't you just start your batch file from a different location?

Even if you can't do that, what you can do is to have a file consisting of only a single line, calling another batch file that doesn't get deleted. This file does everything - starting the java program, doing all the clean up, and even including restoring the original batch file so that you can run it multiple times.

Comment: Adding another file somewhere else is unfortunately not an option in this case. I have access only to the very folder which is being deleted, so I would create another file reaching to the same kind of crash.

Comment: Perhaps you can open the batch file in Word (or using some other mechanism) to force an exclusive lock on the file, then when the Java program tries to delete it, the deletion will fail.

Comment: Interestingly, if I set launch.bat to read only, it can't be deleted by delete.bat, but I still never reach `echo "launch end"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running launch.bat via a `cmd /c launch.bat`, which will try to transfer control back to the calling batch file when it's done, run it by simply doing: `launch.bat`
This will transfer control (think of it as a goto instead of a call) to the batch file, so it wont try to return control to a file that no longer exists.

Comment: I actually added the `cmd /c` after I witnessed that calling directly launch.bat caused the same problem.

Comment: Calling with `cmd /k`is slightly better because I can see the echo "delete end", but I still can't reach "launch end".

Comment: What I'm saying is that the launch.bat command should be the very last thing the batch file does, any cleanup code should go into launch.bat.